# Alternative to MooTools Form Validator

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, mootools

I am trying to find an alternative to Form.Validator from Mootools. The script is taking a handsome **300 ms** to execute which is what I am trying to optimize. Is there any other JS library which can validate forms or can anybody please suggest a leaner approach which consumes less execution time? Complexity vis-a-vis Mootools Form.Validator is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

300 ms? come on :). According to mootools.net jQuery selectors are faster than their selectors.

Just run this test: http://mootools.net/slickspeed/

You could always resort to [jQuery Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) if you are into [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).